# Form through ajax is not submitting

Tags: yii2

I want a progress bar while submitting the form through ajax but the issue is that if the form is submitted the progress bar does not work and when the progress bar is shown the form is not submitted.I cannot understand what's going on.When i hide the ( data: {tenure_id ,due-date} ) the progress bar is shown but the form not submitted.

### Form

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Tenure;
use app\models\Sectors;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\BillGenerate */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="bill-generate-form">

    <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">
            Bill Genrate
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'create']); ?>
            
            <?= $form->field($model, 'tenure_id')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(tenure::find()->all(),'id', 'tenure_name'),
            ['prompt'=>'Select Tenure','id' => 'tenure_i'])?>
              
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date">Due Date</label>
                    <input type="Date" class="form-control" name ="due-date" id="date">
                </div>
             

            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Genrate Bill'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','id' =>'save']) ?>
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 


 <div class="form-group" id="process" style="display:none;">
        <div class="progress">
       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="">
    </div>

</div>


<script>
 
     $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $('#create').on('submit', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        
     
        $.ajax({

         url:'<?= Yii::$app->homeurl?>bill-generate/create?tenure_id=25&due-date=2021-02-11',
         method:"GET",

         //data: {tenure_id ,due-date},

         beforeSend:function()
         {

          $('#save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          $('#process').css('display', 'block');
         },

         success:function(data)
         {

          var percentage = 0;

          var timer = setInterval(function(){
           percentage = percentage + 20;
           progress_bar_process(percentage, timer);
          }, 1000);

         }
        })
       
      });

      function progress_bar_process(percentage, timer)
      {
       $('.progress-bar').css('width', percentage + '%');
       if(percentage > 100)
       {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $('#create')[0].reset();
        $('#process').css('display', 'none');
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
        $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
        setTimeout(function(){
         $('#success_message').html('');
        }, 5000);
       }
      }

     });
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe the submittion of the form only takes little time so you can't see it!

Comment: @EmmaGrove no,i waited for it but nothing happened

Comment: I meant it happens so fast. Add console.log("Before Send") to the beforeSend function to see if it works correctly

Comment: @EmmaGrove "beforesend" works perfectly

Comment: The issue is that when i comment the data( data: {tenure_id ,due-date},) progress bar is shown but data not submitted but when i uncoment the data( data: {tenure_id ,due-date},) then data submitted but the bar not shown

Answer (score 0):

Use data option of ajax. You can send data object to server by `data` option in ajax. It's not a good practice passing query string in the url.

Your code should be something like this..

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?= Yii::$app->homeurl?>bill-generate/create",
    type: "get",
    data: { 
        tenure_id: 25, 
        due-date: 2021-02-11
    },
    beforeSend:function(){
        $('#save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#process').css('display', 'block');
    },
    success: function(response) {
        //Do Something
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
    }
});
```